# How to create boost rule for type facet (itemtype) in hybris?

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

Can anyone help me how to create boost rule of a type facet.

Comment: An example of what you mean would be very helpful.

Comment: I want show product 1st then recipe .How achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

To configure a boost value rule for an indexed field (Facets ..) you have to change your `ConfigurableSolrIndexedProperty`, so you can do that via an impex like :

```
INSERT_UPDATE ConfigurableSolrIndexedProperty;solrIndexedType(identifier)[unique=true] ;name[unique=true];boostValue
                                             ;myIndexedType        ;myfieldName             ; 80
```

Comment: this solution is  not working for the hybris ver 6.3 can you help?